# Updating multiple columns of df from another df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, **df1** and **df2**. I want to update some columns(not all) of df1 from the value which is in **df2** columns(names of common column is same in both dataframes) based on key column. **df1** can have multiple entries of that key but in **df2** each key has only one entry.

```
df2 :
   party_id  age person_name  col2
0         1   12       abdjc  abc
1         2   35       fAgBS  sfd
2         3   65        Afdc  shd
3         5   34      Afazbf  qfwjk
4         6   78      asgsdb  fdgd
5         7   35       sdgsd  dsfbds
```

```
df1: 
     party_id  account_id         product_type  age         dob   status  col2
0           1           1              Current   25  28-01-1994   active  sdag
1           2           2              Savings   31  14-07-1988  pending  asdg
2           3           3                Loans   65  22-07-1954   frozen  sgsdf
3           3           4  Over Draft Facility   93  29-01-1927   active  dsfhgd
4           4           5             Mortgage   93  01-03-1926  pending  sdggsd
```

In this example I want to update age, `col2` in **df1** based on the value present in **df2**. And key column here is `party_id`.

I tried mapping **df2** into dict with their key (column wise, one column at time). Here `key_name = party_id` and `column_name = age`

```
dict_key = df2[key_name]
dict_value = df2[column_name]
temp_dict = dict(zip(dict_key, dict_value))
```

and then map it to df1

```
df1[column_name].map(temp_dict).fillna(df1[column_name])
```

But issue here is it is only mapping the one entry not all for that key value.In this example `party_id == 3` have multiple entry in **df1**.
Keys which is not in **df2**, their respective value for that column should be unchanged.

Can anyone help me with efficient solution as my **df1** is of big size more than 500k? So that all columns can update at the same time.
**df2** is of moderate size around 3k or something.

Thanks

Comment: can u post ur expected output dataframe

Comment: @sammywemmy , Expected df1 will be
`df1: 

     party_id  account_id         product_type  age         dob   status  col2

0           1           1              Current   12  28-01-1994   active  abc

1           2           2              Savings   35  14-07-1988  pending  sfd

2           3           3                Loans   65  22-07-1954   frozen  qfwjk

3           3           4  Over Draft Facility   65  29-01-1927   active  qfwjk

4           4           5             Mortgage   93  01-03-1926  pending  sdggsd
`

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't come in formatted form.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join first, then get columns with are same in both DataFrames to `cols` and replace missing values by original values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates('party_id'), on='party_id', suffixes=('','_'), how='left')
cols = df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns).difference(['party_id'])
df[cols] = df[cols + '_'].rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_')).fillna(df[cols])
df = df[df1.columns]
print (df)
   party_id   age person_name    col2
0         1  25.0       abdjc    sdag
1         2  31.0       fAgBS    asdg
2         3  65.0        Afdc   sgsdf
3         5  34.0      Afazbf   qfwjk
4         6  78.0      asgsdb    fdgd
5         7  35.0       sdgsd  dsfbds
```